# count in excel - a text to multiplied to a number in the adjacent cell

Tags: excel, count

i have listed items in the first column like Radiance, Luminance, Vibrance. And in each adjacent cell is a number that reflect how many is to be counted per item

Example: in A1 is Radiance, A2 is Luminance, A3 is Vibrance. in B1 is 4, B2 is 2, B3 is 1

I wanted to get a count of 4 for Radiance. I tried countif but it just count the number of occurrence of "radiance" and i would just get 1.

how can i count "Radiance" so that it would be multiplied to its adjacent cell, and that i would get a count of 4?

please help me. thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 1st column is a label, 2nd column is a number? I presume labels appear multiple times but with different numbers next to them (eg another Luminance in A4 with a 5 in B4)? Sounds like you are doing a SUMIF not a COUNTIF. But more specifically SUMIFS. To get the total of the numbers with the Radiance label you would use

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3, A1:A3, "Radiance")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but with multiple texts to search for? In this particular example, I tried to something similar to
=SUMIFS(B1:B3, A1:A3, "Radiance", A1:A3, "Luminance")
in hopes of getting B1 + B2 = 4 + 2 = 6
but I get 0 instead.

Comment: I think easiest would be to do 2 separate SUMIFS and add them together. So =SUMIFS(B1:B3, A1:A3, "Radiance") + SUMIFS(B1:B3, A1:A3, "Luminance")